# How to make a list of id's or loop using multiple id's in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find out how to make a list of variables or preferably a loop that identifies the id's. Here is an example.

```
thumb1 = document.getElementById("image1");
```

But instead of it being "image1", I want it to go all the way up to image15.
I'd much rather have a loop with the code above that identifies the id's from "image1" to "image15". I am fairly new to Javascript so any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var elements = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  var id = "image" + i;
  elements.push(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

But the smarter thing to do would be to just add a single class to all of your image elements and use it in combination with querySelectorAll:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="image1" class="image" />
  <img id="image2" class="image" />
  <img id="image3" class="image" />
</div>
```